# Can SVM be used for dimensionality reduction from n dimensions to n-1?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, svm

Consider a case when I have data that has $n$ dimensions and I want to transform this data into $n-1$ dimensions.

For this problem in PCA we project all data points to a $n-1$ dimension plane preserving the variance.

If I draw a hyperplane using SVM (that will be a $n-1$ dimension plane) and project all data points to that plane, how will it differ from the PCA plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different hyperplanes are given by optima of their respective objective function. For PCA this will be maximization of retained variance. For SVM, it's the hyperplane with the maximum margin separating two classes.

The hyperplanes can differ wildly, since you can construct a data set of two classes which is best separated in the direction of lowest variance.

Btw, this is only the case for a linear SVM. If you are using a Kernel, you are not necessarily projecting to an n-1 dimensional space.